# Magento Cache No such File

Tags: magento-1.9, cache

I have the following in my logs which appeared after updating the M2EPro Module.

> fopen(var/cache/mage--9/mage---33f_m2epro_extension_M2ePro_Config_Module_data): failed to open stream: No such file or lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php

I have tried clearing the cache but there must be something embedded somewhere as the record keeps coming back.

How can I stop Magento trying to create/open the non-existant cache record?